# I need to specify a field name different than the table for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given I have an Artifact model and a User model: I would like to define two Artifact fields, opened_by and assigned_to, who values are User ids and inherit all of the proper association methods.

**What is the proper belongs_to or has_one or has_many options I should set?**

The goal is to be able to reference the user's name through the statement `hld.assiged_to.name` where *hld* is an artifact.

Thanks for the help. I've gotten myself confused with terminology with all of the reading i've done on the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is what I determined was correct.

> class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
>     belongs_to :project
>     belongs_to :opened_by, :class_name => 'User'
>     belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name
>   => 'User'

The first argument in the belongs_to specifies the field to reference. The second indicates the model/class to use as the reference.